# Linker error LNK2001

Tags: c++, constructor, linker, visual-studio-2012

When I try to create an object I get a LNK2001 error in Visual Studio, it's a problem with the constructor I think since changing the constructor changes the error.

```
Customer bob("Bob", "25 Bob Lane", "01bob82", "M", "bob/bob/bob");
```

This line gives this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
Customer::Customer(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class 
std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Customer@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@0000@Z)    D:\Dropbox\Work\C++\C++ Assignment\C++ 
Assignment\driver.obj
```

Customer class that contains the constructor:

```
#pragma once
#include "l_list.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Customer
{
private:
    l_list<Account> accounts;
    string name;
    string address;
    string telNo;
    string sex;
    string dob;

public:
    Customer(string name, string address, string telNo, string sex, string dob)
    {
        Customer::name = name;
        Customer::address = address;
        Customer::telNo = telNo;
        Customer::sex = sex;
        Customer::dob = dob;
    }

    void createAccount()
    {
        cout << "What type of account?";

    }

};
```

Comment: This usually means that your are including the wrong version of the header file or linking with wrong version of the runtime library. Your INCLUDE and LIB pathes should point to the same SDK version.

Comment: It's a linker error. So, looks like your project does not include `Customer.cpp`. Or you're using `class Customer` via old (or wrong) library.

Answer (score 10):

If you have linking error then syntactically your code is OK otherwise you'll get compiler errors.

What you should check(or add) is path in Dependencies property of the project that uses Customer class. In VS you can find it "Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies". Seems that linker can't find the external library with Customer implementation. You can successfully compile your project cause all #include are correct but you fail on the stage of linking just because of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

What's there looks OK to me.  Check other things, like make sure your namespaces are right, or there's not another/conflicting "Customer" definition, etc.  Try commenting out large sections of code or reducing your code to a small test case.

Comment: Are you sure this is okay? Since he calls Customer::name, this looks as if it should be a static reference, but it isn't. He should call Customer(string _name), and then init name with _name instead if I read it correctly.

Comment: yes it's ok it's basically saying use the namespace of the `Customer` object... although i personally wouldn't do it that way, i'd use `this->name = name` or assign it like `Customer( string name... ) : name( name ) ... {}`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exact same problem. This is how I fixed:

Use `#include<string>` instead of `#include "string.h"` in the file calling `Customer` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It turned out that one necessary function was commented out. When I uncommented this function, the error disappeared.