# Error LNK2019 LNK2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, codeblocks

I'm supposed to be compiling a source code given by the clients(Coded almost a decade ago) , the project folder contains a ".cbp" file and a vc project file. And when i try and compile it in code blocks, the files are broken (Error: there is a version difference , the project is being coded in version 1.5 and the present version i have is 1.6). But when i look for version 1.5 , there are no links. Also, when i take the code to visual studio 2008 , it compiles , but i get the following two types of linking errors and there are 1300 of them.

1) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FX::FXApp::FXApp(class FX::FXString const &,class FX::FXString const &)" (??0FXApp@FX@@QAE@ABVFXString@1@0@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl osimain(int,char * *)" (?osimain@@YAHHPAPAD@Z)   main.obj    test

2) error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __thiscall FX::FXObject::onDefault(class FX::FXObject *,unsigned int,void *)" (?onDefault@FXObject@FX@@UAEJPAV12@IPAX@Z) cictrackmanager.obj test

What m i doing wrong ? Is the lib file corrupt?

Comment: Where does FX::FXApp comes from? Do you have sources that define namespace FX { class FXApp {...}; };, or do you have a 'libFX.lib' or equivalent?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634193/linker-error-lnk2001

Comment: i have added linked it properly to FOX tool kit. A certain GUI kit. I had multiple errors while compiling and it seems to have sorted out when i added the fx.h and linked. The code compiles , only the linking seems to be an issue.